# Mask passwords in key value list regex

Tags: python, regex, passwords, mask

I have a list of key value pairs:

```
gkketl1Pwd=SDFDSFSFD_213213#asdsad,tech1User=WQEWQQW,techPwd=sdfdsfdM9S,gkkhistPwd=FDSFDDF_WISD01#sad,render1Pwd="SADcyx12321321,213213,recoveryPwd=asdsaSA"ycNJ,9CB9PAJ2w4AbqBHB!,trustStorePwd=test,
```

I would like to log this string but I do not want to print out passwords. Instead of logging out passwords, I would like to mask them before.

I am using Python and at the moment the following expression is used to mask the passwords:

```
maskedValue=re.sub("([\\w]*Pwd=)(.[^,]*)", lambda m: "%s*****" % m.group(1), args[1])
```

Unfortunately, the code does not fully work if the password contains a comma. So does anyone know how to fully mask passwords which contains a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extend the pattern to match any `,` that is not followed with 1+ word chars and then `=` or end of string:

```
(\w*Pwd=)([^,]*(?:,(?!\w+=|$)[^,]*)*)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5wWLpV/3)

**Details**

- `(\w*Pwd=)` - Group 1: zero or more word chars followed with `Pwd` substring
  and an equal sign
- `([^,]*(?:,(?!\w+=)[^,]*)*)` - Group 2 matching

  - `[^,]*` - any 0+ chars other than `,` characters
  - `(?:,(?!\w+=|$)[^,]*)*` - zero or more consequent occurrences of:

    - `,(?!\w+=|$)` - a `,` that is not followed with 1 or more word chars followed with `=` symbol or end of string
    - `[^,]*` - any 0+ chars other than `,` characters

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3sAQvG):

```
import re
s = 'gkketl1Pwd=SDFDSFSFD_213213#asdsad,tech1User=WQEWQQW,techPwd=sdfdsfdM9S,gkkhistPwd=FDSFDDF_WISD01#sad,render1Pwd="SADcyx12321321,213213,recoveryPwd=asdsaSA"ycNJ,9CB9PAJ2w4AbqBHB!,trustStorePwd=test,'
maskedValue=re.sub(r"(\w*Pwd=)([^,]*(?:,(?!\w+=|$)[^,]*)*)", lambda m: "{}*****".format(m.group(1)), s)
print(maskedValue)
# => gkketl1Pwd=*****,tech1User=WQEWQQW,techPwd=*****,gkkhistPwd=*****,render1Pwd=*****,recoveryPwd=*****,trustStorePwd=*****,
```